# Toggle mist on / off in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, volumetrics

I've created some mist in my World settings using Volume Scatter in the Volume section.

Is it possible to quickly turn it on and off for rendering, so that I can create a render with mist, and then render one with a transparent background when I need it?

At present I have to delete the Volume Scatter, render the scene with the transparent background, then add the mist again.

Many thanks for your help,
Ian

Comment: can't you just unplug the node in shader editor?

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised where the node settings for the World were. Found them now.. That works great.